# change font size of English words in captions in a Persian report

Tags: captions, fontsize, xepersian

I am writing my thesis in Persian via using "xepersian" package.
I set the main font by using the following commands,

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xepersian}

\settextfont[Scale=1.3, ItalicFont=*, ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.32}, BoldItalicFont=* Bold, BoldItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.32}]{B Zar}
\setlatintextfont[Scale=1.2]{Times New Roman}
```

For adjusting the font of captions, I am using the following comands,

```
\defpersianfont\BZarScaleOne[Scale=1]{BZar.ttf}
\deflatinfont\TimesNewRomanScaleOne[Scale=1]{Times New Roman}
\DeclareCaptionFont{MyFont}{\fontsize{11pt}{0}\selectfont \BZarScaleOne} % Zar 11
\captionsetup{font=MyFont}
```

The problem is that when I use `\lr{}` for writing somthing in English in the caption, it is written with the same size as the latin words in the main text. How can I change the size of latin words in the captions?

Comment: An MWE would be useful, so that no guessing has to be done (just some sample/dummy text, not your real document). What does `\lr{\large ...}` or `\lr{\small ...}` do?

Comment: @Cicada you are right, commands `\lr{\small ...}` and `\lr{\large ...}` change the font size. But, I have a lot of English words in about 30 figure captions! So, I am looking for an easy solution that can change the default font of the English words in the captions.

Comment: Can you supply an MWE so that there is something to start experimenting with? Dummy text is sufficient. For example, if I wanted to test out a `\lrcap` definition (say, `\newcommand\lrcap[1]{\lr{\small #1}}`, how can I test it to know if it works in your circumstances? For example, there might be a conflict with a package or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change `CaptionFormat` for this purpose the same as below:

```
\DeclareCaptionFormat{Mformat}{%
    \fontsize{39pt}{42pt}#1#2#3%
}
\captionsetup{font=MyFont,format=Mformat}
```

These are Your `codes`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1.3, ItalicFont=*, ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.32}, BoldItalicFont=* Bold, BoldItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.32}]{XB Zar}
\setlatintextfont[Scale=1.2]{Times New Roman}

\defpersianfont\BZarScaleOne[Scale=1]{BZar.ttf}
\deflatinfont\TimesNewRomanScaleOne[Scale=2]{Times New Roman}
\DeclareCaptionFont{MyFont}{\fontsize{11pt}{0}\selectfont \BZarScaleOne} % Zar 11


\DeclareCaptionFormat{Mformat}{%
\fontsize{39pt}{42pt}#1#2#3%
}
\captionsetup{font=MyFont,format=Mformat}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}
\begin{document}
\parindent=0cm
\begin{figure}[H]\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{imagefile}
\caption{\lr{Text}}
\end{figure}
و در متن فارسی از
{\color{blue}\lr{Text}}
می‌توان بهره گرفت. در صورت نیاز از
{\color{red}\TimesNewRomanScaleOne Text}
نیز می‌توان بهره گرفت.

در جدول نیز داریم:
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
4&5&6&4&5&6\\
\hline
7&8&9&7&8&9\\
\hline
\end{tabular}\centering
\caption{\lr{Text}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

And this is Your `output`:

[image]

Good luck.